# If L2 regularization parameter is high and learning rate low, can cost of cross entropy loss function increase?

Tags: regularization, backpropagation, cross-entropy

I coded a neural network from scratch. When regularization parameter is too high and the learning rate too low, cost increases. I suspect that the added cost (associated with regularization) to loss function is responsible for this. When the regularization parameter is set to zero I always get a nice decrease in cost function. Can you please explain what is happening?

Comment: You said that you coded the network from scratch. Have you tested the code and established that all parts of it are working correctly? I would be concerned about hidden semantic bugs in a scratch-build network library because neural networks are complex to program.

Comment: I suppose my network works because back-propagation via numerical derivatives offers similar results and when weights are initialized within reasonable distance from local optimums (up to 10 std's) the network performs well across 30 runs. This network has two nodes in the hidden layer and 1 output node, and is categorizing a noisy XOR dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$L_2$ regularization is basically adding a parabola with a minimum at the origin to the loss surface. How steeply the parabola rises depends on the magnitude of the $L_2$ penalty. If the penalty is too large, then the effect of regularization will overwhelm the signal from the cross-entropy loss, because the shape of the surface is so distorted by the massive penalty for increasing the norm of the weights from 0.

If you imagine starting in some vicinity near zero, moving further from zero will increase the magnitude of the penalty dramatically. If the *increase* in the penalty is larger than the *decrease* in cross-entropy loss, then the *net effect* is that the total loss will increase.

This is one of the reasons that I prefer to track the total, penalized loss separately from the penalty and the classification loss. Basically, track all of these quantities separately to make this kind of unusual behavior obvious.

Comment: I really appreciate this. Thank you very much!